# Implementation of associative array

Tags: java, data-structures

write a function which decodes a URL-encoded string into an associative array.  If there are two parameters with same name, the value should be stacked as an array.

For example, the string

```
a=1&b=2&a=hello&apple=9&apple=digital
```

would be converted to the associative array:

```
array( 'a' => array(1,'hello'), 'b'=> 2, 'apple' => array(9,'digital') )
```

Comment: Are you actually expected to implement an associative array, or just store data into it? Because the standard library already provides one...

Comment: As such I do not need to implement one. But I was under the impression that java does not a data structure like associative array.

Comment: @dcrooney: This is not homework. It was a question I came across while practicing for interviews.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  One important point to learn about SO is that it is NOT a place where you can post your homework questions and expect someone to provide you an answer.  If you've done the work and written the code and then have a specific question about something you don't understand, post the code and ask the question.  What you have posted so far is exactly the wrong way to do things here.  Also, if it's homework then add the `homework` tag.

Comment: @Jim: I am not able to figure out the data structure. I tried using Map, but I need a way to store multiple values for the same key.

Comment: @Jim: This is not homework. I am not in college.

Comment: @Hozefa, consider using a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: That is too open-ended for SO.  If you don't understand the assignment then you need to talk to your prof or TA.  If you want help here, try Googling for "Map with multiple values per key" and if that doesn't provide the answer then repost a question with that title and _show your work_.

Comment: *multiple values for each key* is not usual for an *associative array*. But as your example output shows, simply put as value an array of the values if there is already a value for this key.

Comment: @Jim Garrison you are getting worked up for nothing . It is a legit question in my opinion and Davin has give the answer.Is your issue with really with the question ? I feel like more with something else.

Comment: @Jim: My issue is to figure out a way to solve the problem. I tried using Hashmap<String, ArrayList<String>>, but not able to exactly get the mapping structure in place

Comment: I will give you the benefit of the doubt.  @davin has answered your question (and should post this as an answer instead of a comment; I'll upvote it).  In the meantime, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Jim, I'd love that upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`

For example:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> m = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("value1");
arr.add("value2");

m.put("key", arr);

System.out.println(m); // {key=[value1, value2]}
```

Comment: Very nice. The "standard" way of implementing a multi-map. Actually, I've so many almost identical implementations of a multi-map`, I wish Java would just ship with one built-in. Seems like such a simple class to add to the JCF.